# NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'label.btn.login' for locale 'en'.

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, resourcebundle

Getting below error while trying to read a label from property file.

WARN : org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'label.btn.login' for locale 'en'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:135)
    at com.home.tms.LoginController.home(LoginController.java:44)

[Package Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg8iV.jpg)

[ClassPath also Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGRdl.jpg)

property file------------------------------------------

```
label.btn.login=Login
```

servlet-context.xml--------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resolves Message code based on user Locale -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="messages" />
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>

<beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.home.tms" />
```

Controller------------------------------

```
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
    model.addAttribute("language", locale); 

    System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("label.btn.login", null, locale));

    return "login";
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your  to include the complete path of the message.properties file

```
<beans:property name="basename"
        value="/WEB-INF/resources/message" />
```